# How Do I check if NSSound is paused in Swift

Tags: swift, nssound

I am able to play a sound in swift with NSSound:

```
var path ="/path/to/file.mp3"
mysound = NSSound(contentsOfFile: path, byReference: false)

mysound!.play() // works!

if (mysound!playing)
{
    mysound!.pause() //works, sort of
}

mysound!playing // is still true.
```

How do I check to see if it's paused?

The docs show that  pause() is supposed to return false if playback already paused, but this doesn't seem to be the case, or I am doing something wrong

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
var path ="/path/to/file.mp3"
mysound = NSSound(contentsOfFile: path, byReference: false)

if (mysound!playing)
{
    var state = mysound!.pause() 
    if(state == false) 
    {
         mysound!.resume() //never gets executed - why?
    }

} else {
   mysound!.play() 
}
```

I could use some help figuring this out! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sound will only be paused if you called pause() and it returns true. The documentation doesn't qualify, but a paused NSSound might technically still return true for playing. This would make sense if `playing` is considered to be "not stopped".

Since you will know if you've called pause(), you can just store another Bool `isPaused`, and use that.

In your second example, you're not calling play(), so `playing` will always return false.